# Windows 8.1 Installation on a Macbook Pro Triple Boot "EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS" error

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 on a Macbook Pro that already has Mac OS X 10.9.5 and Ubuntu 15.04 installed on it. I created a usb from the iso downloaded, and it boots up successfully into the windows installation screen. I've already fixed one error where it said that it couldn't install onto an MBR drive: it turned out that Disk Utility had converted my disk into a hybrid MBR so I simply made a new protective MBR with gdisk. The installation is fine up until I get to the partitioning screen. I have left empty space at the end of my drive, and I tell it to install windows onto that empty space. It doesn't complain, and moves on to copying files. However, it then gives me an error saying that my EFI System Partition is NTFS formatted and needs to be FAT32 formatted. As my EFI System Partition is in fact FAT32 formatted, I'm at a bit of a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Try doing a file-level backup of the ESP (create a tarball or zip file from OS X or Ubuntu), unmount the ESP, wipe it clean with `dd` (as in `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1` from Ubuntu -- but be ***very careful*** with that command, and an error could cause *serious* problems), create a new FAT32 filesystem on it, re-mount it, and restore your backup. This will erase any stray data that might be causing a misidentification of the filesystem type.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that... It's a bit scary.